# I change something on dropdown box with JS, but innerHTML wont return with the changed content

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

I have a list:

```
<select id = "opt">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

lets do this:

```
alert (document.getElementById('opt').innerHTML);
```

it will print that:

```
<select id = "opt"><option value="a">a</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="c">c</option></select>
```

no problem yet. Now I change the selected item:

```
for (var count = 0; count < document.getElementById('opt').childNodes[0].options.length; count++)
{
 if (document.getElementById('opt').childNodes[0].options[count].value == 'b') { document.getElementById('opt').childNodes[0].options[count].selected = true; break; }
}
```

and print it again:

```
alert (document.getElementById('opt').innerHTML);
```

it again will print:

```
<select id = "opt"><option value="a">a</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="c">c</option></select>
```

but I excepted something like that!

```
<select id = "opt"><option value="a">a</option><option value="b" **selected="selected"**>b</option><option value="c">c</option></select>
```

so `.innerHTML` doesnt follow the changes. How to fix it?

Comment: and in the browser, B item is actually selected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is the difference between properties and attributes. The `selected` attribute is copied into the `selected` property when the element is created. You are changing the property, but that doesn't change the attribute.

You can see the difference between setting the property and the attrute here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Pec9j/

Comment: @JohnSmith: You can do the same using the `setAttribute` method in Javascript: `document.getElementById('opt').childNodes[0].options[count].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');`.

Comment: @JohnSmith Hmm... You asked this same question few days ago, and you've got this same answer for it...?

Answer (score 1):

Java script is a client side language. After page is loaded then javascript is applied, so it won't change the page source already loaded. If you want to know which element is selected-

```
var value = opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: but sadly I need to know the content of dropdown box

Comment: No, the `innerHTML` doesn't return the original source code, it creates new source code from the elements. However, it uses the attributes to create the code, not the properties.